# Javascript regex to match "1v1" or "30v30" etc

Tags: javascript, regex

I have strings of text such as

```
$40 : Solo 1v1
$100 : Team 3v3
```

I need a regex that will ignore everything except the `INTvINT` pattern so that the only thing returned would be the "1v1" or "3v3".

I know the regex in PHP would be something like this, but I don't know how to achieve the same thing in Javascript:

```
return preg_replace('#.*([0-9]+v[0-9]+).*#i', '$1', $str);
```

Comment: This regex will match `1v2` as well.

Comment: `/([0-9]+v[0-9]+)/g` works for any number + v + another number

Comment: @X.L.Ant - The requirement was `INTvINT`, not `xVx where x is an int`.

Comment: @mikeb As all the examples matched `xVx`, I just wanted to point that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using this regex: `/(\d+)v(\1)/g` you will match 4v4 but not 4v3

```js
var text = "$40 : Solo 1v1\
$100 : Team 3v3"

console.log(text.match(/(\d+)v(\1)/g));
```

- **\d+** - one or more digit characters
- **\1** - backreference to group #1

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this?

`"asdfasdfsadf1v1".match(/.*([0-9]+v[0-9]+)/)[1]`